# Compiling with gfortran instead of ifort

Tags: gfortran, intel-fortran

I've got a program that's been optimized for ifort, however I'd like to compile it using gfortran instead. Here are the flags provided:

```
FCFLAGS=  -Vaxlib -CB -mcmodel=large -O -openmp -DOMP
```

I've had a look in the manual entries for both to try and find a corresponding options, but I haven't been able to find anything (other than -openmp for -fopenmp, which I knew already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, an option by option equivalence table:

```
ifort          gfortran         Commentary
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-Vaxlib                         Enables old VAX library compatibility
                                (should not be necessary with gfortran
                                 and newer ifort versions)
-CB            -fbounds-check   Enables array bounds check at run-time
-mcmode=large  -mcmodel=large   Enables large memory model
-O             -O2              Enables optimisaiton
-openmp        -fopenmp         Enables OpenMP support
-DOMP          -DOMP            Preprocessor option (defines the OMP symbol)
```

Note that enabling bounds checking and large memory model would slow down code execution. Also note that `-O` alone enables different level of optimisations with `ifort` (equivalent to `-O2`) and with `gfortran` (equivalent to `-O1`). Also note that `ifort` optimises much more aggresively than `gfortran`. You might need to provide more options to fine tune the latter in order to reach performance on par with that of `ifort`.

Comment: Is there a full equivalence table somewhere?

Comment: @gregmacfarlane, I don't think so. But one could construct it by reading the manuals.