# Compiling in gfortran with makefile

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

I have received a bunch of .f95 files to be compiled. The only info included regarding its compilation is the order in which these has to be compiled and that the files are in free-form. Besides that there is a Makefile but it is a Makefile made for Intel Fortran Compiler. I know nothing about Fortran and just need to make use of the code. I do not have access to Intel Fortran Compiler and gfortran in macosx is my only available choice. I compiled similar code previously in a similar way and it worked fine. Nevertheless I get multiple errors and nothing happens.

As I said the MakeFile is not complex and is split in three main sections. How could I "translate" this to gfortran syntaxis and compile the code. Is there an equivalence of options between the two? I enclose an abridged version of the MakeFile.

```
Mine
% ifort -o BIN1.exe -O3 -diag-disable 8291 file1.f90 file2.f90 ....

% ifort -g -check bounds -o BIN1n.exe -O3 file1.f90 file2.f90 ....

% ifort -g -debug full -traceback -check bounds -check uninit -check pointers -check output_conversion -check format -warn alignments -warn truncated_source -warn usage -ftrapuv -fp-stack-check -fpe0 -fpconstant -vec_report0 -diag-disable 8291 -warn unused -o BIN.exe -O3 file1.f90 file2.f90 ....
```

Comment: Welcíme. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortan questions and take the Welcome [tour].

Comment: Check this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Option-Summary.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the ifort flags to gfortran flags. To the best of my knowledge this can only be done by reading the documentation of ifort and gfortran. I'm no expert but:

- maybe -fpconstant can be replaced by -fdefault-real-8 (if I understand correctly this gfortran flag has the effect of the ifort flags -r8 and -fpconstant),
- maybe -fpe0 can be replaced by using -ffpe-trap=XXX.

PS: You can find some equivalence at the page [Compiling with gfortran instead of ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335141/compiling-with-gfortran-instead-of-ifort)